# why IIs not load default page in web-application

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications

I am publishing  my web-application project (file system)(in asp.net 4.0) and run with IIs but when loading the web ,IIs isnt loading default page  (login.aspx). and load list of all webpages as a link list.
i am seting login.aspx as default page in the web-application.
Pleas guide me.

Comment: what is it loading, are there any exceptions in the error log or displayed on screen?

Comment: loading all web pages on my project as a linklist,

Comment: please edit your question and the `web.config` section where you set `login.aspx` as your default page.